# Aten U232a not working in Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: usb, serial-port

I have ubuntu 18.04.6, and i want to use my Aten USB-RS232 cable (the 35cm one).After plugged it in, I check dmesg | grep ttyUSB, I get results:

```
[  344.775472] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1186.547300] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1189.537071] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1604.174552] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1644.872046] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

(This is after a few times plug/unplug.)

Then, I check ll -IF /dev/ttyUSB0, result is:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Mac  16 08:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So it is being detected. But when I try to open with putty. It just say "Unable to open serial port". I don't have other apps that are using the port. And not sure why it's not working.

On the same USB port, I plugin a USB drive, and it works normally. So the port is actually OK. Just unable to use with the Aten cable? The Aten cable works ok in Windows. So if anybody have any ideas pls help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution.

Basically it is just a permission issue. in the ll -IF result, we can see user it belong to is root, and group is dialout. I login as my username, so thats why it cannot work. What needed to be done, is add my username (ie ubuntu user-that u can findout by typing whoami in terminal) to the dialout group.

The command is:

```
sudo adduser [username] dialout
```

And then, logout and login again or reboot ubuntu to make effect.